# Verify ifAnyGranted from a TagLib

Tags: grails, spring-security, taglib

How I can verify that "at least one of the roles is granted" from a TagLib?

So, I want to use something like:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
```

but in the groovy file of my TagLib.

I am using [Spring Security Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code in your taglib:

```
class MyTagLib {

  def myTag = { attrs, body ->
      if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR")) {
      // do your stuff...
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: At first I thought I should create an instance for SpringSecurityUtils, but it is a static class.

Thanks for the reply. It has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your taglib:

```
class MyTagLib {
  def springSecurityService // injected by Spring

  def myTag = { attrs, body ->
      def loggedIn = springSecurityService.loggedIn
  }
}
```